# expo development client error: No scheme specified for development client

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to get EAS builds and development clients working on Expo SDK 44, but I ran into the following error in http://localhost:19002/:

```
Error loading DevTools
No scheme specified for development client
```

Unfortunately, there isn't any additional logs regarding this error.

Here is my eas.json file:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.48.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "releaseChannel": "dev2",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleDebug"
      },
      "ios": {
        "buildConfiguration": "Debug"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "releaseChannel": "preview1",
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "releaseChannel": "prod4"
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

And my app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Truffle",
    "slug": "simmer2",
    "version": "1.0.7",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "truffle-tg",
            "project": "truffle-tg",
            "authToken": "c5dc914d80434bdca0762c1404179552e6695d7813114928945fc2c1c9fab08a"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.simmer2.foodie",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.6",
      "infoPlist": {
        "NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "Truffle accesses your library so you can upload a picture for your profile.",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Truffle uses your location to find restaurants near you."
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "AIzaSyDD2MM_1D1ztXv8iAzVReIQUVjetfAfyoo"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "AIzaSyBGnK6cBCTMxM5O2be5pwi-zVoIWNBsdVA"
        }
      },
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
      "package": "com.simmer2.foodie",
      "versionCode": 7
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "sentry-expo"
    ]
  }
}
```

I did add import 'expo-dev-client'; at the top of App.tsx file, because according to the documentation (https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/), this improves the error messaging during the development process, but I didn't see any additional error messages.

Do you have any guidance on why the build does not work on the dev client? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

7 months has passed, so guessing you found a way. My suggestion would be to add a scheme to the `app.json`:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Truffle",
    "slug": "simmer2",
    "scheme": "truffle"
    "version": "1.0.7",
    ...
```